realsense2.dll compilation problems
Required Info:
Camera Model    Intel RealSense SR305
Firmware Version    v2.50.0
Operating System & Version  Windows 11
Platform    PC
SDK Version v2.50.0
Language    opencv/python
Segment YOLOv10
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Warning LNK4199 /DELAYLOAD:/realsense2d.dll ignored; no imports found from /realsense2d.dll rs-depth-quality C:***\librealsense-master\build\tools\depth-quality\LINK 1
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Warning LNK4199 /DELAYLOAD:/realsense2-gld.dll ignored; no imports found from /realsense2-gld.dll rs-depth-quality C***\build\tools\depth-quality\LINK 1
...
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/python/readme.md#windows


The paths in your error log are very weird. Are they set up to use a variable that you forgot to define perhaps?

First of all, I need to use librealsense cmake and compile it with visual studio. Then I should be able to access the real sense SR305 camera with yolov10, but I get an error.
